# Possible to include (r.js) optimized file directly?

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, dynamic-loading, r.js

after optimizing a require.js project (pushing everything into one "big" `.js` file), is there any way to circumstance the need to include the require.js file (which then only loads one single `.js` file) and load the compiled file directly instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a light weight AMD loader like [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond). You will still need a loader anyway as your compiled JavaScript still use `define` and `require`.